# MSE iPhone App: Math display in problem titles

Tags: support, mathjax, ios-app

For the MSE app for the iPhone, the math display is OK for the main body but is displayed as input code in problem titles - is there any way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231730) from Meta Stack Exchange may be relevant (though not very helpful).

Answer (score 1):

> As explained in my [meta post announcing the addition of MathJax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213825/please-add-tex-rendering-on-the-android-app/214264#214264) this is a known issue. However, it's really unlikely for this to be resolved since it means turning *everything* in the application to `WebView`s rather than just question and answer bodies. -- [Kasra Rahjerdi](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221930/259867), SE Mobile Team Lead

I'll add a bit more of explanation: the titles are displayed by the native code of the application (written in Objective-C for iPhone and in Java for Android). MathJax is written in JavaScript and does not display anything by itself, its output consists of markup code to be interpreted and displayed by a *web browser*.

The reason we get to see formulas in post bodies is that they are rendered by a web browser engine, not by the app directly. The app pastes the rendered view into its interface, it's sort of like a browser window inside of an app.

If question lists were also rendered by a web browser, the app would be a glorified bookmark to the mobile version of the site.

Comment: Side remark: having tried both, I prefer using mobile site to the Android app .

Comment: Side side remark: Having tried both, I prefer to use the browser with "full site" even on my Nexus 4.

Comment: That's a corner remark, then.

Comment: What's the side side side remark, then? I'm not a big fan of the homological approach to this. :-P

Comment: Side side side remark: I'm very happy with the iOS app on a 6+, but I'm mostly commenting on it while on the go.